# Blender 2.75 Time Node

Tags: node-editor, shaders, osl

Mybe somebody knows, how to get Time node in Node Editor in blender 2.75
I am using Open shading Language ?

Comment: What do you mean by time node?  Do you mean the current frame?

Comment: There is a time node for compositing, but not cycles materials. Can you provide a link to where you heard about the time node?

Comment: @sambler what does the compositor time node do?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is a node that does the same thing as the *time* node in the compositor.  Unfortunately there is no single cycles node that does this.  However one can be constructed rather easily.

First add a *value* node and plug it into the *color* on an *RGB curves* node.  Then keyframe the value node's value to be `0` at frame 1 and `1` at the last frame.
[image]

Then select the value node and hop over to the *graph editor*...
[image]

... select the keyframes, press <kbd>T</kbd>, and select *linear* interpolation.
[image]

The output of the RGB curves node will be the same as the output of the time node would be in the compositor.  You could eliminate the RGB curves node and just edit the interpolation curve in the graph editor; but while that will give you a *little* more control it would be more cumbersome to tweak.  But it is an option if you need the extra control.